# How to test java reflections code using JUnit

Tags: java, unit-testing, reflection, junit, junit4

I have a java class that invoke a method via reflection. That method create database connection and perform database operations. i want to test my reflections code using junit. Is there any way to do that?

Please find my code snippet below.

```
    Class DaoImpl {

    public void setResult(String result) {
        this.result = result
    }

    public String getResult() {
        return this.result;
    }

    public void doDBoperation() {
        Connection connection = getConnection();
        Statement st = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("Select column_name from table");
        if(rs.next()) {
            result = "value";
        }
    }
}


Class ReflectionClass {

    public void invoke() {
        Class<?> noParam = {};

        Class<?> clazz = Class.forname("DaoImpl");
        Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("doDBoperation", noParam);

        method.invoke(clazz.getNewInstance);
        System.out.println("This is it");
    }
}
```

How to write JUnit test case for my ReflectionClass?

Comment: Could you fix the compilation errors in the code snippets first?

Comment: code snippet is just a mock code.

Comment: Posting correct code would increase the chance of getting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real "pure unit test" way of testing *ReflectionClass**. Normally, you would do a unit test by providing a **mocked** instance of that class to your production code; then you could use the mocking framework to verify that the expected method was called.

But in your case, you created code that is simply **hard** to test (if you want to learn how to address that part, you might want to watch these [videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79)). You are basically calling "new" directly in your production code; thus there is  no way to insert a mocked object. And beyond that, you also can't mock those reflection methods.

The only option to **maybe** get this code tested would be to use Mokito together with PowerMock. But I am not an expert in that area, and can't promise you that it will work.

My recommendation to you: step back first and figure if you can get **away** from using reflection, or at least: to separate concerns here. Because as said: your **production design** looks **weird**; and instead of spending hours to get that somehow unit tested; you should rather spent a fraction of that time to improve your design! "Hard to test" typically means "design could be improved"!

Meaning: first you create an **interface** that denotes the function that you want to test. Then you separate your production code of *ReflctionClass*, like:

1. One part is responsible for providing an instance of that interface (and that code could be using **reflection** to do its job, if that is really required)
2. The other part then calls the method(s) you want to be called on that interface object.

By doing so, you get **two** parts that you can test independently of each other!

Edit: what I mean by "bad design" - why are you using reflection to do both - *object creation* and *method invocation*? You see, you could simply cast that created object to its correct class (at least if you have an interface defined there) and then do a ordinary method call on that typed object.

Answer (score 0):

As @GhostCat suggested `PowerMockito` could be used to try to mock `DaoImpl`'s constructor. Here's the code:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ReflectionClass.class)
public class ReflectionClassTest {

  @Test
  public void invoke() throws Exception {

    DaoImpl mockedDaoImpl = PowerMockito.mock(DaoImpl.class);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(DaoImpl.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mockedDaoImpl);
    new ReflectionClass().invoke();
    Mockito.verify(mockedDaoImpl, Mockito.atLeastOnce()).doDBoperation();
  }
}
```

But, it doesn't work. PowerMock doesn't manage to mock the constructor when invoked through reflection.